# R Plot: spead out axis labels evenly

Tags: r, plot

I'm currently struggling with finding out, how to spread the axis labels evenly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
plot(1:10, type = "p", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(1, at = c(1:10))
axis(2, at = c(1:10))
grid(nx = 10, ny = 10)
```

[image: Plot]

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the data points in the center of the respective grid box and to have the labels (1-10) to be in the center. How can I achieve this?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the help file for `grid` tells you, when you need more control of the grid lines, you should draw them directly with `abline`. When you want precise control of the axis limits rather than allowing R to choose pretty limits, you specify `xaxs = "i"` and `yaxs = "i"` in your initial plot command.

```r
plot(1:10, type = "p", xlab = "", ylab = "", 
     xlim = c(0.5, 10.5), ylim = c(0.5, 10.5), yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i")
abline(h = 2:10 - 0.5, v = 2:10 - 0.5, lty = "dotted", col = "lightgray")
axis(1, at = c(0:11))
axis(2, at = c(1:10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The issue I have now though is that the box of the first and last row/column are not the same size as the others. That's what I initially intended to do, I guess I should've elaborated on what I wanted better, sorry...
Is there a way to make all the boxes the same size?

Comment: @Wolke see my update. You can add `xaxs = "i"` and `yaxs = "i"` to ensure you get the exact axis limits you requested.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Allan Cameron that when you want that much control it is best to switch tools to something like `abline`.  But if you really want to use grid, you can do so by explicitly setting the limits of your plot:

```
plot(1:10, xlim=c(0.5,10.5), ylim=c(0.5,10.5), xaxs='i', yaxs='i')
grid(nx=10, ny=10)
```

You may want to do this even if using `abline` since it will make the corner and edge boxes be the same size as the others (and center the points in those boxes).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! It looks just like what Allan Cameron wrote and has therefore still the one issue I explained under Allan Cameron's response. I want all the "boxes" of the grid to be of the same size. 
Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: @Wolke, I added the plot that I get running my code.  The boxes are all the same size.  What code are you running and what does your plot look like?

Comment: sorry, you're totally right, I just ran the code again. Maybe it was the resolution of the plot window or maybe I just had something in my eyes. My mistake!

Comment: @Wolke, I still think that Allan's answer (now that it has been updated to also give equal boxes) is better, I would suggest accepting his instead of mine.

Comment: I was actually having a hard time deciding which answer to accept and chose yours because your initial answer already did what I intended to do. 
I went ahead and accepted Allan's answer. Still, thank you very much for your help :)